# Tensorflow lite runtime does not install on pi4 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and python 3.8.2

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I have a pi4 running ubuntu 20.04 LTS and python 3.8.2. I have installed the Coral USB TPU accelerator. Now I am trying to install the Tensorflow Lite Runtime from the below link for arm64 and python 3.7:
`pip3 install https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl`
I get this error:

> ERROR: tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Is there a compatible Tensorflow lite runtime available somewhere else for Linux ARM64 over ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8 ?

or do I need to compile on my platform?

Answer (score 1):

*Update as of 28 September 2021:* there are aarch64 wheels for tflite-runtime version 2.5.0 and 2.5.0.post1 for python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9. Please see https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/tflite-runtime/.

---

You are trying to install a python 3.7 wheel using python 3.8. You need to either use python 3.7 on your system or use a python 3.8 wheel.

It seems that there is no https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp38-cp38m-linux_aarch64.whl file (a python 3.8 wheel) so you will need to downgrade your system to python 3.7.

Comment: Second this answer, we haven't supported python3.8 yet, unfortunately

Comment: Where can I find a wheel of 2.1.0.post1 for mac Bigsur I am using python 3.7 but returned error. Could you please help me.

Comment: @waqasakram - i don't see macosx wheels for bigsur for version 2.1.0.post1, but look at https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/releases, which has wheels for tflite-runtime version 2.5.0.